# Make .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 work on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, server, localhost, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I have implemented a website on localhost and then put it on an online server.
So basically what I want is to use url-rewrite for the 404 page. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404  http://example.com/myfolder/error.php
```

This works properly online. How do I make redirect work even when I'm on my localhost?

Comment: check whether fileinfo module is installed or not?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar how?